# How to load page breaks from file in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have an xlsx file with manually inserted page breaks, however when I load it into openpyxl with

`wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_to_workbook)`

and then call:

`for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    print(sheet.page_breaks)`

the output is:

`<openpyxl.worksheet.pagebreak.PageBreak object>
Parameters:
count=0, manualBreakCount=0, brk=[]`

which shows no page breaks in the file

When I open up the xlsx file in page break mode in excel I see the breaks exactly where they should be. 
Does anyone know how I should go about this?

Comment: It's not currently supported in Openpyxl (v2.4.8) - page break data is not read from file. It should be a simple change to fix it. I'll update when I get a chance to submit a fix.